# JavaScript / jQuery Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an object of SharePoint Search Navigation Nodes from its classes.

```
var nodes = $("div.ms-qSuggest-listItem");
```

I am getting the nodes object and now wanna get the value of "_promptString" and "_url".

I tried the following:

```
nodes[0].getAttribute("_url");
nodes[0].innerHtml;
nodes[0].value;
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post som html?

Comment: `nodes[0].innerHtml;` is, at the very least, an error; you're looking (I assume) for `nodes[0].innerHTML;` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties do not seem to be attributes of the DOM element but properties of the DOM object. Try the following:

```
nodes[0]._url;
nodes[0]._promptString;
```